# Текст внутри кнопки не двигает, также фиолетовая линия слишком сильно расширился Css + Html

Tags: html, css, html5, css-selectors, css-grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image]

Изучаю css и html, только не бейте)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab";
  background: url(img/bg.png)
}



.header {
  display: flex;
}

.main-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  width: 800px;
}

.text1 {
  color: #7c6db0;
  margin-top: 189px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 59px;
}

.text2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 59px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #7c6db0;
  background-color: #7c6db0;
}

.pic {
  margin-top: 94px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 39px;
}

.teeth-text {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.btn-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 340px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #1eb8b0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 16px rgba(0, 215, 255, 0.44);
  background-color: #1eb8b0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-230deg, #01c4e0 0%, #01b3e0 100%);
}

.btn-text {
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-2 {

  margin-left: 30px;
  float: left;
  width: 360px;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 16px rgba(0, 215, 255, 0.44);
  border: 2px solid #1eb8b0;
}

.btn-text2 {
  color: #01b3e0;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="main">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="main-text">
          <div class="text1">Имплантация зубов</div>
          <div class="text2">в Санкт-Петербурге</div>
          <div class="pic">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="teeth-text">
            Имплантированный зуб<br>
            не отличить от настоящего!</div>
          <div class="btn">
          <div class="btn-1">
          <span class="btn-text">Записаться на осмотр</span>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-2">
            <span class="btn-text2">Посмотреть видео</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="img/wm.png" alt="">
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Опишите вашу проблему подробнее. Что "текст внутри кнопки" должен двигать?

Comment: Я прикрепил фотографию)

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab";
  background: url(img/bg.png)
}



.header {
  display: flex;
}

.main-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  width: 800px;
}

.text1 {
  color: #7c6db0;
  margin-top: 189px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 59px;
}

.text2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 59px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #7c6db0;
  background-color: #7c6db0;  
  text-align: center; /*выравниваем текст по центру блока*/
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 70%; /*делаем блок с текстом чуть меньше основного*/
}

.pic {
  margin-top: 94px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 39px;
}

.teeth-text {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex; /*используем флекс для выравнивания кнопопк*/
  flex-direction: row; /*указываем направление выравнивания*/
}

.btn-1 {  
  width: 340px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #1eb8b0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 16px rgba(0, 215, 255, 0.44);
  background-color: #1eb8b0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-230deg, #01c4e0 0%, #01b3e0 100%);
}
.btn-1, .btn-2{
  display: flex; /*используем флекс для выравнивания текста в кнопках*/
  align-items: center; /*выравниваем по оси У*/
  justify-content: center; /*выравниваем по оси Х*/
}

.btn-text {  
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #ffffff;  
}

.btn-2 {
  margin-left: 30px;  
  width: 340px;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 16px rgba(0, 215, 255, 0.44);
  border: 2px solid #1eb8b0;  
}

.btn-text2 {
  color: #01b3e0;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 26px;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="main">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="main-text">
          <div class="text1">Имплантация зубов</div>
          <div class="text2">в Санкт-Петербурге</div>
          <div class="pic">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="teeth-text">
            Имплантированный зуб<br>
            не отличить от настоящего!</div>
          <div class="btn">
          <div class="btn-1">
          <span class="btn-text">Записаться на осмотр</span>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-2">
            <span class="btn-text2">Посмотреть видео</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="img/wm.png" alt="">
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```